# Maven - project specific classpath

Tags: java, maven, log4j, dependencies, classpath

I have a maven project which is imported project into my services. The project is a logging facade which  uses log4j.

The issue is that log4j is a maven dependency which is now on the classpath so the other developers will be tempted to use the log4j log manager rather than the the logging facade that I have created.

It there any way I can make the log4j maven import specific to that project?

Comment: Why did you write your own instead of using slf4j?

Comment: @slf4j, because I am doing funky stuff and the slf4j method signatures are not useful for what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

What you basically want is to have the transitive dependency log4j on runtime scope. I don't think you can do that, since log4j is compile scoped for your facade and your facade is again compile scoped for the services (if I understand correctly). According to the table here: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies, 
the scope of log4j is set to compile scope.

In any case, the other developers can use your namespace to import your facade.